# Create a column at specific location in dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

I want to create a new variable at a specific location. I can create the variable with `mutate` and then reorder with `select` but I rather would prefer the `tibble:add_column` way of doing it.

This is a simple example with the iris dataset :

```
library(tidyverse)
## This works fine
iris %>% mutate(With_mutate = ifelse(Sepal.Length > 4 & Sepal.Width > 3 , TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
         select(Sepal.Length:Petal.Width, With_mutate, everything()) %>%
         head()

## This works also
iris %>% add_column(With_add_column = "Test", .before = "Species") %>%
head()

## This doesn't work
iris %>% add_column(With_add_column = ifelse(Sepal.Length > 4 & Sepal.Width > 3 , TRUE, FALSE), .before = "Species") %>%
head()
Error in ifelse(Sepal.Length > 2 & Sepal.Width > 1, TRUE, FALSE) :
  object 'Sepal.Length' not found
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could tell me why my `ifelse` statement doesn't work with `add_column`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that `mutate` or `summarise` etc get the column value based on specifying the symbol, but here `add_column` wouldn't.  So, we can extract the column with `.$`

```
iris %>% 
   add_column(With_add_column = ifelse(.$Sepal.Length > 4 & 
                                 .$Sepal.Width > 3 , TRUE, FALSE), .before = "Species") %>%
   head()
#Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width With_add_column Species
#1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2            TRUE  setosa
#2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2           FALSE  setosa
#3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2            TRUE  setosa
#4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2            TRUE  setosa
#5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2            TRUE  setosa
#6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4            TRUE  setosa
```

Just to make it compact, the value of logical condition is `TRUE/FALSE` so, we don't need an `ifelse` i.e.

```
add_column(With_add_column = .$Sepal.Length > 4 & .$Sepal.Width > 3, .before = "Species")
```

can replace the second step

Comment: Many thanks @akrun for this super fast answer. Good tip also to get rid of the indeed useless `ifelse`